# Altbeacon android library 2.1-beta2 crashes

Tags: android, ibeacon-android, altbeacon

I know that this release is not intended for production purposes but I would like to know if this exception only happens to me.
I have a testing application, and when I try to instantiate a BeaconManager I get the next exception:

```
Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.radiustesting/com.example.radiustesting.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageManager(ContextWrapper.java:94)
    at org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager.verifyServiceDeclaration(BeaconManager.java:676)
    at org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager.<init>(BeaconManager.java:215)
```

This is my simple Activity class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  implements BeaconConsumer{
    protected static final String TAG = "RangingActivity";
    private BeaconManager beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);

     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
           beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0216,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
             // set the duration of the scan to be 1.1 seconds
            beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(1100l); 
            // set the time between each scan to be 1 hour (3600 seconds)
            beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(1000);

            beaconManager.bind(this);

        }
...
```

Is anyone getting same exception? Thx

Comment: yet another premature Context usage ... context is valid in onCreate not in <init>

Comment: i am having a similar problem with 2.1.3 version, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28962436/altbeacon-application-crashes-on-android-tab . could u resolve the issue??

Comment: Yes, you should initialize beaconmanager, inside onCreate method

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  implements BeaconConsumer{
    protected static final String TAG = "RangingActivity";
    private BeaconManager;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
       beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
       beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0216,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
         // set the duration of the scan to be 1.1 seconds
        beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(1100l); 
        // set the time between each scan to be 1 hour (3600 seconds)
        beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(1000);

        beaconManager.bind(this);

    }
```